# Can I ask for a raise based on acquired knowledge and experience, but no new responsabilities?

Tags: salary, raise

I will soon complete my first year in a company, which I joined after my graduation.

While I haven't received new responsibilities, I have contributed in different ways and gained both hands-on experience and knowledge related to tools/processes mostly related to this company.

1. In many other questions I see "getting new responsibilities" as the primary reason for a raise, so I wonder do knowledge an experience alone are a good reason for a raise?
2. If yes, shall may raise request remain limited or can it be consistent?
3. Company also paid for a course, can I put that in the list of acquired knowledge or is it not a good thing to do given they paid for it?

Comment: Does your company have periodical evaluations of your performance or similar? Have you excelled on those evaluations?

Comment: Yes, there will be a performance review

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How should I properly approach my boss if I'm feeling underpaid?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/1025/how-should-i-properly-approach-my-boss-if-im-feeling-underpaid)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I have contributed in different ways [...]

Depending on what your contributions consist on, those could be valid reasons to ask for a raise if they added significant value or income to the company.

> [...] and gained both hands-on experience and knowledge related to tools/processes *mostly related to this company*

I would say that gaining experience and knowledge on the tools/processes used in your company is not a strong reason for asking for a raise, as possessing that knowledge and experience is actually part of your job.

Gaining experience on the tools of your company is what we call "learning the ropes". Doing so is expected from any employee, so that is why it may not be a strong reason to ask for a raise.

> Company also paid for a course, can I put that in the list of acquired knowledge or is it not a good thing to do given they paid for it?

Exactly, not the greatest idea or argument. The company paid for this course, so you can "learn the ropes" and be up-to-speed with those tools used internally. If you don't know how to use these tools then you wouldn't be able to do a proper job.

Putting it in other way, the company invested extra money on you, so you get to know the things and tools needed for you to do your work as expected.

Now, you mentioned in comments that *there is an upcoming yearly evaluation of your performance*. *This* will be a good time to learn how your performance is going, and to probe if you are in a position to ask for a raise based on your results (chances are, if you excelled on your performance, they are already thinking of giving you a raise).